# Use the value instead of displaying it

Tags: php, wordpress, buddypress

I'm trying to use bp_group_name() in

```
if (bp_group_name()!='General') {
//code
}
```

Instead of using the value of `bp_group_name()` in the IF, it displays the value on the page.

Sorry if the way I described this was a bit off...

Comment: What does the bp_group_name() function do? I've got a feeling it does not return a value, but echoes it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`bp_get_group_name()` ?

http://bp-dev.org/phpxref/_functions/bp_get_group_name.html

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a function that returns a value instead of a function that echoes a value.

```
if (bp_get_group_name() != 'General') 
{
    //code
}
```

[**Here's a discussion of using code that's similar to yours and probably trying to do a similar thing**.](http://buddypress.org/community/groups/how-to-and-troubleshooting/forum/topic/how-to-exclude-a-group-from-the-groups-loop)

Answer (score 0):

```
bp_get_group_name()
```

http://phpxref.ftwr.co.uk/buddypress/nav.html?_functions/index.html